# Issue with AngularJS/WebAPI application in IIS Website Folder

Tags: angularjs, iis

Here is my issue.  I have a Angular/WebAPI project hosted in IIS 8 within a subfolder of the domain.  When I access the site with a trailing slash after the folder name, everything works ok.  But if I leave off the trailing slash, when Angular adds the '#/' for the route, it breaks.

```
Example: http://www.domain.com/folder/ becomes http://www.domain.com/folder/#/ <- OK
         http://www.domain.com/folder becomes http://www.domain.com/folder#/ < - Breaks
```

The AngularJS Template I started with does not have this issue.  I do not understand what is causing this issue and I don't know how to proceed.

Additional Info on the project
I am using MVC Bundles to minimize the javascript and css
I have WebAPI controllers in the same project
I am using Microsoft OWIN for authentication in the same project
Other than this initial URL issue, the project runs correctly.
I can not reproduce this issue in Visual Studio, but VS doesn't run in a folder.
I can post Angular routes if needed.

Comment: what is happening when it "Breaks"?

Comment: It loads the initial html page.  But on that page, there are relative links to html pages in angular directives.  Those aren't loading, probably due to the directory being 'folder#/' instead of 'folder/'.  I need to figure out why the #/ is being added without first adding a / to the end of the folder name.

Comment: To be clear, the trailing / is handled by your server. The #/ is handled by angular. From the Angular standpoint, the behavior you're describing is correct. You probably need to set a rewrite rule of some type in your IIS configuration. I don't know IIS at all, so you'll need to dig into it on that side. this might help: http://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/

Comment: Hi Luke. Did my answer fix the problem? Let me know if it didn't. If my answer was helpful, can you upvote it and award the answer? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with how relative pathing works in HTML and not something specific to Angular. This is a result of the original specs for URLs and relative links before there was really even a concept of virtual URLs.

Relative links on your HTML page go from the same base as the HTML "doc" itself. Therefore, if the url is:

```
http://domain.com/folder/
```

then, your browser anchors relative URLs at

```
http://domain.com/folder/[relativePathHere]
```

The browser assumes that it's looking at the default doc (index.html, home.htm, etc.) in that folder -- what originally was an index of the files in that directory. However, without the trailing slash, the browser thinks "/folder" is actually a file called "folder" that is sitting in the root doc directory for the server (as it has no way of differentiating -- it doesn't care one way or the other whether there is a file extension). So, all relative paths are anchored at

```
http://domain.com/[relativePathHere]
```

That's why you're having issues with your relative pathing without the trailing slash. To correct this, you will want to put a rewrite rule into place in IIS. This way, you will be immediately redirected to the version that has a trailing slash before the default HTML file is delivered. This is a very common thing to do (not just for this type of case -- it's also important for SEO so that crawlers don't think that there are two distinct pages).

Check out tip #1 in the following link: http://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/

Follow the directions for adding the trailing slash, and you should be set.